React Router doesn't work properly in React / Vite Project
I want to build a react app with vite. "npm run dev" works fine but when I want to build it and open the index.html in the new /dist folder I am coming to an empty /index.html side with no errors in the console. I tried to change the paths but that did not work. It has to be the react-router because everything else works fine. But I don't know the exact problem and I am not able to finde it out.
I hope you can help me.
PS: Down below you find the relevant code. If you need more information please ask.




index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/img/djServiceLandLogo.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Vite + React</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.jsx"></script>
  </body>
</html>

package.json
{
  "homepage": "https://www.enian-gashi.xyz/",
  "name": "dj-service-land-production",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@gsap/react": "^2.1.1",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue-jsx": "^3.1.0",
    "gsap": "^3.12.5",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^5.2.1",
    "react-router": "^6.23.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.23.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.66",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.22",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.19",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.34.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.6",
    "postcss": "^8.4.38",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.3",
    "vite": "^5.2.0"
  }
}

vite.config.js
import { resolve } from "path";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  base: "",
  plugins: [react()],
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        main: resolve(__dirname, "index.html"),
      },
    },
  },
});

main.jsx
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "/src/App.jsx";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import "./index.css";

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

App.jsx
import "./App.css";
import React from "react";
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Event from "./pages/Event";
import Hochzeit from "./pages/Hochzeit";
import Terminanfrage from "./pages/Terminanfrage";
import AboutMe from "./pages/AboutMe";
import Impressum from "./pages/Impressum";
import Datenschutz from "./pages/Datenschutz";
import MissMatch from "./pages/MissMatch";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Routes>
        <Route index path="/" element={<Event />} />
        <Route path="Hochzeit" element={<Hochzeit />} />
        <Route path="Terminanfrage" element={<Terminanfrage />} />
        <Route path="AboutMe" element={<AboutMe />} />
        <Route path="Impressum" element={<Impressum />} />
        <Route path="Datenschutz" element={<Datenschutz />} />
      </Routes>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;

dist index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="./img/djServiceLandLogo.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Vite + React</title>
    <script type="module" crossorigin src="./assets/main-mOYYtr3v.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" crossorigin href="./assets/main-B4zcMpNs.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>


Are you just opening the index.html file into the browser? The app needs to be hosted/served to a client. Are you running/hosting/serving the app?

I opened the file via the vs code live host.

Are you trying to run a development server like npm run dev, or are you trying to build and serve it locally for some testing, like npm run build and npm run preview? Does this help answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71703933/what-is-the-difference-between-vite-and-vite-preview

@EnXan Open with the live server with dist as the root directory, not the project root.

Yes npm run dev works and so does npm run preview. But when I upload the files to my plesk webserver I get the same black screen as with npm run build and the error: GET https://www.enian-gashi.xyz/assets/main-C3vlRv9Y.js net::ERR_ABORTED 500 (Internal Server Error)

Could it be possible to fix the problem by not just upload the dist folder but the whole project?

How is your "plesk webserver" setup/configured? Does it return the root index.html file for all page requests into the app?

I uploaded the config to the original question

I could try to change the startup file to index.html

Looks like your "Application Startup File" App.js is missing. Do you need to create that file or specify a different startup file, maybe Main.jsx? Do you need to setup any "Run Node.js Commands" commands?

I tried it with index.html but know I get the Error: in the console Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

Okay I solved the problem. I had to upload the dist folder to my webserver and changed the paths to the dist folder. Thanks for your help!
